# Error on Redmine plugin time_trackers_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine

I'm using redmine with the plugin redmine_time_tracker. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: INSERT INTO `time_trackers` (`issue_id`, `user_id`, `time_spent`, `paused`, `started_on`) VALUES(8, 3, 0,0, 0, '2011-04-19 08:35:19')):
  vendor/plugins/redmine_time_tracker/app/controllers/time_trackers_controller.rb:13:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

```
Redmine Version: Redmine 1.1.2
Plugin Version: 0.4
```

Comment: Did you rake when you installed the plugin?  It sounds like the db is out of sync with how the object model is trying to save itself.

Comment: @Milimetric I am new to Ruby and Rails, What would be the command for this?

Answer (score 0):

When installing a redmine plugin you should follow this tutorial: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins. The command I'm thinking you missed is: `rake db:migrate:plugins RAILS_ENV=production`.  But just to be sure, go through the install carefully.

Comment: How do I check the creation of the insert in Ruby on Rails?
I would check if it is being created right.

Comment: You could login to your database and look at the table.  This plugin works for me so it's almost surely a deployment issue.  I'd try reinstalling.